# Alternative to using flags when iterating through objects in python

Tags: python, excel, loops, flags, xlrd

I have a script that compares values between two .xls sheets using xlrd. By default it lets me look for similarities, and writes them to a txt file. If I pass an in an argument, I can look for devices unique to each .xls, and write those to txt file. Right now, I iterate through the rows in each .xls, and mark a flag as True when it finds a similarity between the two files. It will only write hosts from the first sheet when the flag is marked False. Here is the bit of code with flags:

```
else:
    for row1 in range(sheet1.nrows):
        inboth = False
        for row2 in range(sheet2.nrows):
            if sheet2.row_values(row2)[0].split(".")[0] == sheet1.row_values(row1)[0].split(".")[0]:
                inboth = True
        if not inboth:
            outfile.write(sheet1.row_values(row1)[0].split(".")[0] + ",File1\n")
    for row2 in range(sheet2.nrows):
        inboth = False
        for row1 in range(sheet1.nrows):
            if sheet1.row_values(row1)[0].split(".")[0] == sheet2.row_values(row2)[0].split(".")[0]:
                inboth = True
        if not inboth:
            outfile.write(sheet2.row_values(row2)[0].split(".")[0] + ",File2\n")
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this without using the "inboth" flag? Is there a solution where I don't need to iterate through both sheets twice?

Comment: The total number of tests is 2xNxM, where N and M are the number of rows in scheet1 and scheet2, respectively. This is O(N^2) in computer science speak and makes you code extremely slow for large data sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the Python `set` data type. http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html Iterate through the first file and put all the devices you find in set `s` then put all the devices from the second filw in set `t`. then do:

`r = s.symmetric_difference(t)`

`r` will have the list of devices in one but not both files.

Comment: Wow, it is so much quicker too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it blazing fast since it is only O(N) now.

Comment: the reason it is quicker is that in your original if file 1 has m lines and file two has n lines you scanned 2*m*n lines. Using sets only 2*(m+n) lines are scanned. `symetric_difference() is also O(m+n).